# JQuery Ajax adding hash in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, struts2

I have this code here that uses struts2-jquery plugin

```
<h4>Choose A task</h4>
    <ul>
        <s:url value="views/ajaxvalidation.jsp" var="ajaxvalidation" >
            <s:param name="menuId" value="1"/>
        </s:url>
        <li><sj:a targets="resultContent" href="%{ajaxvalidation}">Ajax Validation</sj:a></li>
    </ul>
```

When I click its content the url is changing to something like this, nothing is changing in the url. it still remains the same, what I want is that when I click the link something like this would happen `www.myapp.com/#ajaxvalidation` . When I run the code anchor tag is translated to something like this

```
<a id="anchor_1365013162" href="javascript:void(0)">Ajax Validation</a>
```

With that given, how would I add a hash in the url?

Comment: When you use AJAX, the URL isn't supposed to change, since you're not loading a new document. AJAX is a transparent communication behind the scenes.

Comment: @Barmar
How would I then add a hash to the url? I need to rewrite the url(or add a hash to it) but load the selected contents with ajax since I have a music player that's being loaded

Comment: Is `document.location.hash = 'ajaxvalidation'` what you're looking for?

Comment: how would I use document.location.hash ?? please provide an example

Comment: @KyelJmD - Barmar's comment above has a full example, that line would add a hash to the url, and all you have to do is show some effort and try it out, and you'll figure this out, as it's really very simple to do.

Comment: Just a plain example of a documentation.location.hash

Comment: @adeneo I tried to run it but nothing happened.

Comment: @KyelJmD - on a wamp server on your computer or on an actual webserver of course, not jsFiddle or similar services  ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is a working example (not considering Struts2):

```html
<html>
<body>
<a id="123" href="">Add Hash</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("id");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can add #id/somename/ programmatically? but this works

Comment: `window.location.hash = 'id/somename/'`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want jump the page then there is a workaround by using the history API on modern browsers with fallback on old ones:

```
if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '#myhash');
} else {
    location.hash = '#myhash';
}
```

Credit goes to [Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/2011/05/change-url-hash-without-page-jump/)