# Add random number to URL without reload for sharing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realise a lot of similar questions exist, but none of them seem to fit my needs.

**Context**

Essentially I have a button that when clicked:

- converts text to morse code
- then removes the button and replaces it with three social buttons.

**Problem**

Essentially, whenever that button is clicked I want:

- the browser to add ?123456 (random number) to the end of the URL to allow that to be shared on social networks.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LLe0shk5/

Comment: If you're doing this server-side, you'll want to issue a 302 redirect to the desired URL. If you're doing it client-side, have a look at [History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) (which will allow you to insert a URL into the browser's history without causing a page reload). If you're doing this to prevent Facebook, etc. from caching the page, there are probably better ways.

Comment: I've done that before with hashes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986231/jquery-ajax-adding-hash-in-the-url Then you can parse that hash later with jQuery after someone visits the link. Although, I like the redirect idea above better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953792/change-url-in-browser-address-bar-without-reload-existing-page

Comment: What's the actual purpose of the number?

Comment: To create a unique URL. Needs to be in the format 'http://example.com/?123456'