# Add an hash in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I would like to know how to add an hash with jquery in an URL when I click on `edito` in a menu ?

Example on click detect this :

```
mydomain.com/edito
```

And transform to this :

```
mydomain.com/#edito
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986231/jquery-ajax-adding-hash-in-the-url check this url

Answer (score 1):

You should detect click on link then prevent the default behaviour and send the use to the desired position in page, and it'll be better if you could add the targeted element `id` as data attribute on `a` tag.

1. Use `data-*` attributes to store the targeted element `id` :

   ```
   <a href='mydomain.com/edito' data-target-id='edito'>Edito</a>
   ```
2. Capture the click on link `a` :

   ```
   $("a").on('click', function(e) {
       //Your code here
   });
   ```
3. Prevent default behaviour by adding `e.preventDefault()` to the event.
4. Use `hash` to send user to the targeted element :

   ```
   window.location.hash = $(this).data("target-id");
   ```

**Full code :**

```
$("a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    window.location.hash = $(this).data("target-id");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
location.hash = "bob"
```